# Python : Facebook Graph API get user details

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to simulate searching for user in Facebook via Facebook graph API. I am using [facebook-sdk](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk)

Below is my code.

```
import facebook

access_token = "MY_ACCESS_TOKEN"
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)

def try_query(string):
    query = 'search/?q=' + string + '&type=user'
    data = graph.request(query)
    return len(data['data'])

#My profile
print (" Pratibha Jagnere : ",try_query("Pratibha Jagnere")) 
# some random name
print (" Stephen Foster : ",try_query("Stephen Foster"))
```

It is giving me below output.

```
Pratibha Jagnere :  0
Stephen Foster :  23
```

I dont understand why it is not giving result for my own name. Any help will be very appreciated.